# How to automate the changing of P4 client specs on a Jenkins build process for multiple build jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, perforce, perforce-client-spec

**Context**:

- One machine that uses Jenkins as a DOS-Jenkins service (not a Windows service).
- Source-Code Management is handled using a Perforce plugin.
- There is another job on the same machine that uses the Perforce plugin to sync files but from a different Perforce server.

**Problem**:

- The first task in the build process is a Windows-batch command that performs a force sync of a particular file.

```
p4 sync -f //depot/directory1/BuildVersion.cs
```

- However, the console output displays the following message:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.jenkins\workspace\<workspace_name>>p4 sync -f //depot/directory1/BuildVersion.cs 
//depot/directory1/BuildVersion.cs - must refer to client '<clientname>'.

C:\Users\<username>\.jenkins\workspace\<workspace_name>>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Steps to try and address this issue**:

- I have tried following the advice in the documentation, which can be [found here](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_client.html#Syntax_conventions_..895), or alternatively, see the image below -- to no avail, possibly because I'm not understanding it.
  [image: P4 build farm configuration]
- I have tried adjusting both build processes manually so that the `p4 config` client specification matches their respective build configurations -- however, the console outputs the same error message.

There is obviously a conflict with the P4 configurations conflicting with one another, and I would appreciate a solution that allows for both build processes to work with different P4 configurations using a DOS-Jenkins infrastructure.

Comment: The sync -f file argument in the console output isn't the same as the one that you say is in the build process. Maybe there's a typo in your batch file?

Comment: @Samwise Many thanks for your response. Turns out that one has to specify the environment variables for both P4PORT and P4USER at the beginning of each build process, otherwise they will conflict with the settings of the opposing build process -- if that makes sense?

Comment: Yup, that makes perfect sense, although it doesn't explain the `//directory1/BuildVersion.cs` vs `//depot/directory1/BuildVersion.cs` mismatch...

Comment: @Samwise Oh wow you are spot on! I completely overlooked that typo -- apologies for the oversight in the OP. I'll be fixing that now. Many thanks for your support.